# Can anyone verify my NN diagram if it is properly drawn?

Tags: neural-network, keras, cnn, convolution

I am working on a Neural Network that can estimate building's carbon footprint based on the set of features and an image of urban surroundings (via CNN).

[image]

I have used Netron to visualize the network (up) but this image is not readable in a publication so I drawn one myself (down).

[image]

Can anyone comment if this is proper representation - especially the last part after the concatenation - I am not sure if there should be 2 or 3 dense layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a special kind of format that needs to be followed as long as the image is clear and readable, which (imho) it is for your case. Regarding the last 2/3 layers, the final layer is the output with 1 unit, so you pictured it correctly, along as the article mentions the output shape (that is not a multi-output situation).

Good luck with publication!

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to ask what do you mean by "that is not a multi-output situation"? How should it be called then? Is this double single output?

Comment: Well you didn't make it explicit on a diagram that each one of "Operational/Emodied Carbon Footprint" is composed of 1 unit, so you might want to add a similar caption like "Dense 1" for each of them. That would make it 100% clear.

Comment: ok, thats a good idea